# Using the same const two different times with cocoa pods: how is it possible?

Tags: xcode, architecture, constants, cocoapods

I am using a `pod` called `MyLib` in a project called `MyProject`. In my project, when I "import" `MyLib`, the file `Pods-MyLib-prefix.pch` contains the following instanciation of a `const`:

```
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

BUT, in the "main" `.pch` (the file `MyProject-prefix.pch`), I am able to instantiate the same const to a different value, without error:

```
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG;
```

It's perfect and I don't have any problem with that but I am a bit surprised. So my questions are:

1. How is it possible to instantiate two times the same `const` in this way? Asking this question, I would like to have more information of the underlying architecture of a project with `pod`s.
2. Can we, in the same way, define several times the same `#define THE_SAME_KEY_WORD`?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have to use extern const int ddLogLevel and const int ddLogLevel to have the same const in your project code as in the library code.

As far as I remember it is like this:
static * only local (within file) definition
const * global constant
extern const * make use of externally defined constant value without problems

Hope this helps.